# CakePHP 3 - Paginating a custom finder

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

CakePHP 3.7

I'm trying to paginate some data from a custom finder and it's either not working or giving errors.

What I have:

```
// src/Model/Table/FiltersTable.php
public function findFilters($rf_keywords = '')
{
    // ...
}
```

The function above, `findFilters()` is a custom finder which accepts a parameter `$rf_keywords` and performs a search across various tables. I know this works because in a Controller I can do this:

```
$Filters = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Filters');
debug($Filters->findFilters('foo'));
```

This outputs an array of data based on searching for a string "foo". However this can return >1000 records so I want to paginate it to 25 per page.

So I've read https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/pagination.html and tried to modify my Controller:

1. Loading the `Paginator` component:

   ```
   public function initialize()
   {
       parent::initialize();
       $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
   }
   ```
2. Setting `$paginate` to use my custom finder:

   ```
   public $paginate = [
       'finder' => 'filters',
       'limit' => 25
   ];
   ```
3. Following the information on the docs above passing in the request data and getting it to paginate:

   ```
   $request_data = $this->request->getParam('pass');

   $customFinderOptions = [
       'filters' => $request_data
   ];

   $this->paginate = [
       'finder' => [
           'filters' => $customFinderOptions
       ]
   ];
   ```

When I do `debug($this->paginate($this->Filters));` it gives a Runtime Exception:

> Unable to locate an object compatible with paginate.

The Controller I'm using is `src/Controller/WizardController.php`. In this case there is no `FiltersController.php` but I don't think that's the source of the error?

Please can someone advise how to get this working?

I'm also unsure how to pass in `$rf_keywords`. Previously I passed it in as a parameter, i.e.

```
$rf_keywords = trim($this->request->getData('rf_keywords'));
$data = $Filters->getFilters($rf_keywords);
```

Since this is request data is it passed in the equivalent of `$request_data` in my code above? I don't see how that would work as it's using a parameter called `pass`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, cakephp has convenient method to create custom finders.

In model, You should create finder like this:

```
// src/Model/Table/FiltersTable.php
public function findFilters(Query $query, array $options = []): Query
{
    return $query 
        ->where(['column' => $options['rf_keywords']]);
}
```

In `WizardsController`, You should load model `Filters` first, then call this finder not directly by calling method `FiltersTable::findFilters()` but by passing finder name as param to `FiltersTable::find()` method

```
/**
 *  @method GET
 *  @return Cake\Http\Response|NULL
 */
public function index() 
{
    $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
    $this->loadModel('Filters');

    $finder = $this
        ->Filters
        ->find('filters' , [
            'rf_keywords' => $this->request->getData('rf_keywords')
        ]);

    $result = $this
        ->paginate($finder)
        ->toArray();

    dump($result);die;
}
```

Remember: In controller `$this->request->getData($param)` allows You to access POST params

To access GET params, You can use `$this->request->getQuery($param)`

Comment: Have you tested this code? It still gives the same error: "Unable to locate an object compatible with paginate."

Comment: Yes sir. Fully tested. This error tells me one important thing: to `$this->paginate()` You should pass instance of `QueryInterface` or instance of `RepositoryInterface`. Not `array` and not `ResultSet`. It looks like Your finder returns some other type than `Query` - You should not execute Query in finder. Executing `Query` is `Paginator` responsibility.

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm returning the `Query` object is the correct solution.